# spring 3 and dwr 3 not working with single configuration file

Tags: configuration, spring-mvc, dwr

I am using Spring 3.0 and DWR 3 in my web app. I have some configuration problem. When i use single configuration file for both tech, then the one which i write at top will work and next will not work. And when i made two different DispatcherServlet then they are working fine.
Here is my web.xml configuration:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>abc-dwr</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>abc-dwr</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my abc-servlet.xml file (which contain only Spring configuration):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr  http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c">
        <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="(service|controller)\*" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

And here another abc-dwr-servlet.xml file (which contain both Spring and DWR configuration):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr  http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DWR SETTING STARTS HERE -->
    <dwr:configuration  >
        <dwr:convert type="bean" class="a.b.c.formbean.XYZ" />
    </dwr:configuration>
    <dwr:annotation-config />
    <dwr:url-mapping />
    <dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="true" />
    <dwr:annotation-scan base-package="a.b.c.dwr" />

    <!-- DWR SETTING ENDS HERE -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c">
        <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="(service|controller)\*" />
    </context:component-scan>
```

Here two file, `abc-servlet.xml` contain Spring configuration and `abc-dwr-servlet.xml` contain DWR and Spring configuration. I have written Spring configuration in both file, coz if i will remove it from 2nd file Spring will not work.
I have tried too much to merge both technology in same configuration file. But only one which i write at top is working and another one is not working. 
Is there any way to merge both of them in same file, or i am doing some silly mistake? please help me.

Thanks
Shams

Comment: No one has any idea to correct this one??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the proper configuration (Spring 3.x + DWR 3 + Tiles) with only one Dispatcher Servlet declared and able to inject Spring services in my DWR controller using annotations:

That very good blog contains lot of useful resources about how to config Spring with many other technos:

Spring + DWR
http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-and-dwr-3-integration.html

Other tutorials:
http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html

Comment: hi, i had gone through this tutorial. but i am unable to identify, where i am doing wrong configuration. Could you check my both .xml files and let me know where i am wrong? or post your config so that i can compare with my config.
Thanks

Comment: Difficult to say with a partial configuration. I had to declare the following bean in a context configuration (I declared it in dwr-config.xml): `<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />`